# PHP coding not working as expected. Can't pass value and math formula is not working

Tags: php

For those that are aware of the component, I'm attempting to edit one of the templates in ZOO 3.1.6 (for Joomla 3.x).

From what I can gather, when going into a category, ZOO first calls the category.php file, which calls the _items.php file, which calls the _item.php file.

The structure for the HTML / columns and rows seems to be done in the _items.php file but I need a value to pass into _item.php.

Here is my _items.php file:

```
<?php
/**
* @package   com_zoo
* @author    YOOtheme http://www.yootheme.com
* @copyright Copyright (C) YOOtheme GmbH
* @license   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html GNU/GPL
*/

// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// init vars
$i       = 0;
$columns = array();
$column  = 0;
$row     = 0;
$rows    = ceil(count($this->items) / $this->params->get('template.items_cols'));

// create columns
foreach ($this->items as $item) {

    if ($this->params->get('template.items_order')) {
        // order down
        if ($row >= $rows) {
            $column++;
            $row  = 0;
            $rows = ceil((count($this->items) - $i) / ($this->params->get('template.items_cols') - $column));
        }
        $row++;
        $i++;
    } else {
        // order across
        $column = $i++ % $this->params->get('template.items_cols');
    }

    if (!isset($columns[$column])) {
        $columns[$column] = '';
    }

    $columns[$column] .= $this->partial('item', compact('item'));
}

// render columns
$count = count($columns);
if ($count) {
    echo '<div class="items items-col-'.$count.'">';
    for ($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++) {
        $first = ($j == 0) ? ' first' : null;
        $last  = ($j == $count - 1) ? ' last' : null;
    $oddeven = (($j % 2) == 0) ? ' row-even' : ' row-odd';
        echo '<div class="width'.intval(100 /     $count).$first.$last.'">'.$columns[$j].'</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}

// render pagination
echo $this->partial('pagination');
```

Here is my _item.php file:

```
<?php
/**
* @package   com_zoo
* @author    YOOtheme http://www.yootheme.com
* @copyright Copyright (C) YOOtheme GmbH
* @license   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html GNU/GPL
*/

// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

?>

<div class="teaser-item">
    <div class="teaser-item-bg<?php echo $oddeven; ?>">
    <?php if ($item) : ?>

        <?php echo $this->renderer->render('item.teaser', array('view' => $this, 'item' => $item)); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

In _items.php I have created the variable $oddeven and am trying to set a text value to this variable to echo as a class in the appropriate spot. But, first my math statement seems to be breaking the script, and secondly I have tried a static variable but it doesn't seem to be picked up in the _item.php file.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In _items.php

```
for ($j = 1; $j < $count; $j++) {
        $first = ($j == 0) ? ' first' : null;
        $last  = ($j == $count - 1) ? ' last' : null;
    $oddeven = (($j % 2) == 0) ? ' row-even' : ' row-odd';
```

Try to make `$j=1;` because the problem probably would be breaking the script is when `$j` is `0` then this function gives an *divide by ZERO* error and thus it breaks the script.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.  Do you have any ideas on how I can get the value of $oddeven into _item.php?  I can't figure that out.  I've tried entering the HTML code into the _items.php file but it messes up the HTML in _item.php.

Comment: Thanks @JimThornton I believe $oddeven actually is a local variable and it dies after the if itself ... how are you actually trying to get the value of $oddeven to _item.php ... The workaround for this might be you can create a new variable in _item.php and use it.

Comment: I Believe I can earn a Vote up and Acceptance this is a answer :) 
Best of Luck !!!

Comment: Unfortunately, there is information in _items.php that I need in order for this to work and _item.php doesn't get it.  I guess I'm going to have to just re-write the whole file.